# How to text-align center to a class with a vertical align?

Tags: css, center, vertical-alignment, text-align

Here is my class :

```
.middle {
  height: 50px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

How can I align my text center? Text-align: center will not work with this type of setup. This class is applied to a span and the span is placed inside of another class. The class that it goes inside of looks like

```
.topic {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 8%;
}
```

Comment: Can you setup a fiddle replicating the issue?

Comment: Consider updating your tags of your question

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zY4t5/
This is a similar example.

Comment: A `span` tag is an `inline` element, so `text-align:center` won't work unless you set it to `display:block`, and you'll notice, if you do this that the vertical align no longer works.

Comment: Exactly, Nick. That is the whole point to my question. Is there a way to do both vertical-align and text-align?

Comment: You need to give a width to the `.middle` class. What's happening is the table is collapsing to the width of its contents rather than filling the surrounding `<div>`.

Comment: Thank you so much Phylogenesis. I was looking at it in firebug and because of the surrounding class I was still seeing the 8% width of that surrounding element and that was hiding the issue. Appreciate it!